# textFieldBeginEditing not working - why?

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I have a textField that can only be saved if it has been altered. So the Save Button is .enabled = NO in viewDidLoad.

If the user edits or changes the textField I want to enable the Save Button. So why isn't this code working?

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    self.ButtonSave.enabled = YES;
}
```

Comment: Have you set the delegate for your `UITextField`? Also nothing to do with the `xcode IDE`.

Comment: As in @interface LocationSpecifyStaticVC () <UITextFieldDelegate> ? If so yes.

Comment: No have you set your delegate for the instance of the `UITextField` you have created? Such as `UITextField *myTextField = [[UITextField alloc] init];` then after creating the instance you have to do `[myTextField setDelegate:self];`.

Answer (score 0):

`didBeginEditing` doesn't fire when the user changed the text, it will fire when he selects the textField (before editing).

You can listen for `UIControlEventEditingChanged` event:

```
[myTextField addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldDidChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];

- (void)textFieldDidChange:(id)sender {
    if (myTextField.text.length > 0) self.ButtonSave.enabled = YES;
    else self.ButtonSave.enabled = NO;
}
```